# Rain & Back pain

Tags: riddle

> To marry me forever is the exception
>   To divorce me is the rule
>   To love me is to show respect
>   To hate me is to show a lack
>   To have me you must make a promise
>   To keep me you must break it

Comment: the wife ? OJ!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> A library book (or similar lending scheme)

To marry me forever is the exception

> You don't normally have library books forever

To divorce me is the rule

> You generally return them

To love me is to show respect

> If you love books, you show then respect by treating them well (regardless of how good a specific book is)

To hate me is to show a lack

> Hating books demonstrates a lack of character (or something)

To have me you must make a promise

> You promise to bring the book back when you sign up at the library

To keep me you must break it

> See above

Answer (score 2):

It is

> Bonding in atoms

---

**Explanation**

---

To marry me forever is the exception

> An atom bonded to another atom forever is an exception.

To divorce me is the rule

> Bonds are made and broken continuously in a mixture.

To love me is to show respect

> Show respect means to share electrons

To hate me is to show a lack

> Lack of electrons causes an atom to not to make a bond.

To have me you must make a promise

> Promise of sharing of electrons

To keep me you must break it

> To make a new bond, the atom have to break a bond.

Comment: ^vote for romantic sensitivity toward science

Answer (score 1):

My answer is:

> The Master/Apprentice relationship in the Star Wars Universe.

To marry me forever is the exception
To divorce me is the rule

> Eventually, the apprenticeship ends. In the Jedi Order, they are trained until they become Jedi Knights; in the Sith Order, generally one betrays the other.

To love me is to show respect

> Generally the master chooses his/her apprentice, and in order to continue to work together harmoniously, the master and apprentice must share a platonic love and show respect and to one other. Examples can be seen in the movies.

To hate me is to show a lack

> Introducing hate into the Master/Apprentice relationship means being disrespectful or unfaithful to each other and, to quote, `"I find this lack of faith disturbing"`.

To have me you must make a promise

> Members of each order take an oath to follow their respective Code. Those in the Jedi Order follow the Jedi Code; those in the Sith Order follow the Sith Code.

To keep me you must break it

> The Sith Code contains the line, `"...my chains are broken"`. From a certain point of view, it can be interpreted as being free, but the apprentice is not free until his chains are broken. In theory, s/he can keep the Master/Apprentice relationship forever by breaking the oath.